# Load python notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I would like to load a text in python notebook that is undirected network.

```
f=open('C:\...\com-dblp.ungraph.txt','r')
```

it is does not work

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBthm.png)

Comment: what happens when you run this line of code? what is the error?

Comment: what's the error message?
Also, most likely the path is wrong, on Windows the path separator is '\', not '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get unicode error because of the `\` , it gives the next character a special meaning and in a regular string you'd need to escape `\` with another `\` (like `'C:\\Users\\micka\\OneDrive Bureau\bigdata\\finalexam\\com-dblp.ungraph.txt'`) In most cases it's actually fine to use single forward slash in paths instead of a `\\` , Windows today and current python versions can handle paths like `C:/Users/` just fine.

Though in your case it just leads to another issue: Google Colaboratory can't access your local files. You have to manually upload it (find the folder-icon on the left pane, open it and drag-n-drop your files there) or check their IO Notebook for other options - https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb